# How to redirect uname.test.com to test.com\uname? Hosting - firebase

Tags: firebase, redirect, hosting, firebase-hosting

The domain test.com has dynamic user subdomains - user123.test.com.
How can I redirect user123.test.com to test.com/user123?
Hosting - **firebase** !

I tried to do with firebase.json and Cloudflare rules - https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427 
Cloudflare does not suit me due to the price of the service.
Firebase.json does not have a subdomain redirect option.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible using wildcards in Cloudflare's Page Rules as described in the link you have already posted.

The issue with redirecting from subdomains is that you need a proxied (orange cloud) DNS record for each subdomain you want to redirect from. You can proxy a wildcard subdomain record on an enterprise plan, alternatively you would have to add the subdomains' records manually or via the API.

Comment: As I wrote earlier - сloudflare does not suit me due to the price of the service. Enterprise plan unreasonably expensive only for this option!

Answer (score 0):

you can try as in the documentation about [redirect rules with url fragments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects)

Try something like this, in your `firebase.json` file:

```
"redirect": [
  {
    "source": ":uid.test.com",
    "destination": "test.com/:uid",
    "type": 301
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: **"*"** and **":"** are allowed only in the path:
`{"source": "/ user /: uid" }` **(ok)**
but not in the domain name!
`{"source": ": uid.test.com /"}` **(not work!)**